# Websphere 6.1 + Hudson + Ant

Tags: ant, hudson, websphere

Running into a problem with an existing application. I'd like to get hundson running to do some CI but I cannot modify the Websphere settings (making changes appears to break the application that I want hudson to test against!)

So this is my current error message:

> We detected that your servlet
>   container is loading an older version
>   of Ant by itself, thereby preventing
>   Hudson from loading its own newer
>   copy. (Ant classes are loaded from
>   bundleresource://22/org/apache/tools/ant/types/FileSet.class)
>   Perhaps can you override Ant in your
>   container by copying one from Hudson's
>   WEB-INF/lib, or can you set up the
>   classloader delegation to child-first
>   so that Hudson sees its own copy
>   first?

Without changing the classloarder delegation (which breaks the existing app) is there a way to update Websphere's ant library? I don't even know where it is, I tried searching for ant-lr but came up with many results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you run Hudson on a separate app server? You can even run it from the embedded servlet container directly from the war.

If you really need to run it on websphere look at the wiki. 
http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/IBM+WebSphere#IBMWebSphere-KnownIssues

Answer (score 0):

Read http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/IBM+WebSphere. It states specifically that you must set child-first class loading on WebSphere 6.1.